# for loop and a list.remove() doesn't remove all the items in the list in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

```
names_friends=["Juan","Efren","Kiki", "Esmoris", "Diego", "Nando"]
for i in names_friends:
    print(i)
    names_friends.remove(i)

print(names_friends)
```

After run this code I got this.

```
Juan
Kiki
Diego
['Efren', 'Esmoris', 'Nando']
```

I would highly appreciate if someone could explain to me why it doesn't remove all the items of the list.Thanks

Comment: Its really not a good idea to change a list while iterating over it

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating

Answer (score 2):

You are changing the iterable *while* iterating over it. So once you delete a object from it, it may skip the next one.

If you iterate over a *copy*, this problem goes away, e.g.

```
for i in names_friends[:]:
    print(i)
    names_friends.remove(i)
```